# How to know that ChangeDetection was executed on specific component?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I'm doing research on how **ChangeDetection** works in Angular.

One way of trigger **ChangeDetection** is to run method `detectChanges()`:

```js
constructor(cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { 
  setTimeout(_ => cd.detectChanges(), 3000)
}
```

It will execute change detection on the component but did not touch any component lifecycle hooks.

So if you try to do `ngDoCheck` or `ngAfterViewChecked` inside the same component:

```js
  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log('ChangeDetection')
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    console.log('ChangeDetection')
  }
```

you will get nothing in the console.

Here you can play with the code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-cd-check?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

So my question is:

Is there a general way (*that will work for all the cases*) to define that **ChangeDetection** was executed on a specific component?

Comment: Pretty sure it should trigger hooks:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/11.0.4/packages/core/src/render3/instructions/shared.ts#L374
A bug maybe?

Comment: Check [this](https://indepth.dev/posts/1053/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular#change-detection-operations), particularly _calls OnInit and ngDoCheck on a **child** component (OnInit is called only during first check)_, so it's called on a **child** component. _It will execute change detection on the component but did not touch any component lifecycle hooks._ - because it's not supposed to do that, it touches them on a child component

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution when inside a template I put a dummy function:

```html
{{realDoCheck()}}
```

and as we know function will be always called when CD tries to rerender the template, so:

```
  realDoCheck() {
    console.log('CD triggered')
  }
```

here is a complete code example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-cd-check-dyudp6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts